# Changing 2D Array Key Names With Another Object's Corresponding Key Containing Vector Coordinates

Tags: javascript

**Goal:** Initialize a blank chess board with each table cell containing (x, y) coordinates, and then populate initial chess pieces by updating the corresponding cells of the chess board by renaming the key with the appropriate chess piece. The coordinates (the key values) would remain the same.

**Problem:** Having trouble changing the key names of the blank chess board with the appropriate chess pieces using the map function.

```
  1) **typeError** from pushing Vector object to an array
  2) **undefined** returned from nested map function
```

Upon researching, a way to change keys would be using either

> Object.keys(myObject).map(key => ({[key]: myObject[key]}));

or

> Object.entries(myObject).map(([p, v]) => ({[p]: v}))

However, I could not get it to work when the **map** function was nested for the 2D array.

```
    const BOARD = `
    wbwbwbwb
    bwbwbwbw
    wbwbwbwb
    bwbwbwbw
    wbwbwbwb
    bwbwbwbw
    wbwbwbwb
    bwbwbwbw
    `;

    const PIECES = `
    rkbqibkr
    pppppppp
    --------
    --------
    --------
    --------
    pppppppp
    rkbqibkr
    `;        

    //class Board    
    static initalize(board, pieces){
    let boardCoords = board.coordinates;
    let pieceCoords = pieces.trim().split("\n").map(l => [...l]);
    let initialPieces = [];
    let startBoard;

    //this is to add the appropriate coordinates of where each chess piece 
    //is at
    //the parameter 'board' that was passed is an instance of the Board 
    //class, where each cell had the appropriate (x, y) coordinates. The 
    //code was exactly the same as below, and it worked. Not sure why it's 
    //not working for below. OUTPUTS: typeError
    this.initialPieces = pieceCoords.map((row, y) => {
        return row.map((ch, x) => {
            if(ch !== '-'){
                this.initialPieces.push(new Vec(x, y)); 
            }
        });
    });

    this.startBoard = Object.entries(boardCoords).map(row, y => {
        key.map(ch, x => {
            if(ch !== "-"){
                ({ [ch]: boardCoords[y][x]});
            }
        });
   });

    return startBoard;
   }}
```

**[Trying to push vector into array]**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

**[Trying to map with .map(item, item2)]**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: row is not defined

**[Trying to map with .map(item)]**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

**[Expected Result]**

> [0]: ["p"]: Vec (x, y), ...

Comment: Did you realize `initialPieces` was declared twice? one using statement `let` and another setting to the lexical context?

Comment: I think you should change this `this.initialPieces.push(new Vec(x, y));` to this `initialPieces.push(new Vec(x, y));`

Comment: I tried taking out this. but it still outputs the same error.